# Processing JavaScript complex object

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache, lodash

I have following JavaScript array `var arr = ['1', '2', '3', '4' ];`

I want to convert this object into a single string such that I it should produce following output: `1 + 2 + 3 + 4`. This is working fine with the help of `join` function.

`arr.join(' + ')` produces the desired output.

**Problem** is my simple array is now been converted into a complex object:

```
var data = [
{
    "key": "1",
    "IsData": true
},
{
    "key": "2",
    "IsData": false
},
{
    "key": "3",
    "IsData": true
},
{
    "key": "4",
    "IsData": false
}
];
```

I can loop over this object and produce the desired result `1 + 2 + 3 + 4`.

**I want to know if there is a smarter way (WITHOUT LOOPING) to get the desired output. May be by using library like lodash or jquery**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map),

```
data.map(function(val){ return val.key }).join(' + ');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Emcyh/)

Answer (score 3):

If you're already using jQuery, it too has a [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) function:

```
var output = $.map(data, function(obj) { return obj.key; }).join(' + ');
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/E7X6m/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for quick help Cory. Marking Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy's answer as the right answer and voting up your answer as he gave the answer first.

Comment: You're welcome! The only thing I would caution is that `Array.prototype.map` did not exist in IE 8 and below, so be aware if you unfortunately have an audience that fits that criteria. jQuery would bridge that gap for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data.reduce(function(pstr, co) {
    return pstr+" + "+co.key; 
}, "").slice(3);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
var data = [ { "key": "1", "IsData": true }, { "key": "2", "IsData": false }, { "key": "3", "IsData": true }, { "key": "4", "IsData": false } ];
var outputString = "";
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    outputString += data[i].key;
}
outputString = outputString.split("").join(" + ");
alert(outputString); // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tz7y5/).

Comment: -1: `I can loop over this object and produce the desired result...I want to know if there is a smarter way (WITHOUT LOOPING) to get the desired output`: You've just reproduced what OP said they were already doing.